# What does xorl $0x0,0x6100 do?

Tags: x86

I know that xorl is used for zeroing out the register.It is equivalent to i=0 in C. But what does $0x0 mean? Also does this instruction reads/writes to the page in page table?

Comment: _"xorl is used for zeroing out the register.It is equivalent to i=0 in C"_. No. `xorl` is used to perform the operation `dest = dest XOR src`, which _in the particular case_ where `dest == src` will result in `dest = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`$0x0` is an immediate constant, zero.   `0 XOR y = y`, just like adding zero to anything is a no-op.  (xor is addition without the carry from bit to bit).

`0x6100` is an absolute memory address.  Was there a segement override on that?  Where was this instruction?  It seems like an unlikely thing to do.  The insn will still fault if that address isn't read/writeable, because xor immediate-0 isn't specially recognized as a no-op.  Besides, the ISA requires it to fault if appropriate, even if the CPU had special logic to not actually do a read-modify-write cycle.